# Как в wordpress исправить конфликт jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Ввел в файл function.php :

```
// Remove themes old version of jQuery and load a compatible version
function my_update_jquery () {
if ( !is_admin() ) { 
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, false, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', my_update_jquery);
```

Данная функция отменяет все коробочные jquery и идет по ссылке. У меня же ничего не происходит.....конфликт как был-так и остался

Comment: В WordPress нет никакого конфликта jquery. Объясните, что у вас установлено дополнительно, что с чем конфликтует, какие ошибки в консоли браузера.

Comment: И третий параметр надо указывать как array ()

Comment: KAGG Design, я импортировал проект с хостинга и развернул на своем локальном сервере,чтоб сделать там некоторые изменения. А библиотека в файле  jquery.js может присоединяться по всему проекту в разных местах и неккоректно работать из-за этого. На фрейверке laravel  я с таким сталкивался, в этом проекте я увидел подключение в нескольких местах разных версий. Поэтому и прописал этот код (выше), чтоб удалить дефолтные и подгружать по ссылке.

Comment: Какой третий параметр Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Не надо трогать jquery в WP, там нет ошибок. Локальный или в сети сервер - неважно.

Comment: Ну какой третий параметр в register_script

Comment: И пока вы не ответите на вопросы в первом комментарии, дискуссия бессмысленна.

Comment: Хммм...хорошо, не буду трогать jquery, поверим Вам, ведь я первый разстолкнулся с редактированием кода на WPю Поэтому вот и задал этот вопрос. Плагины: advanced-custom-fields, complete-open-graph, cool-mobile-menu, google-maps-easy, iconic-navigation,itro-popup, jquery-colorbox, mobile-menu, mobile-navigation-menu, open-graph-protocol-framework, php-code-for-posts, popups, post-to-posts, qtranslate-x, seo-ultimate, slicknav-mobile-menu, tw-pagination, wdes-responsive-mobile-menu, wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol,wp-translitera

Comment: логи апача говорят 200, а если внести в function.php код выше, то выдает 304

Comment: Ок, а что в консоли браузера?

Comment: - error in parsing value for ' margin-top'. Declaration dropped.    -Unknown property ' windows'. -   Expected color but found 'solid\9'   - таких ошибокштук 50 + / -

Comment: Это в каких файлах?

Comment: screen.css, public.css, bootstrap.min.css, font-awesome.min.css, mobmenu.css, styles.css, jquery-1-10.1.min.js, comand

Comment: Ну и какое отношение css имеет к jquery? Вот вы бы начали с ответов на мой первый комментарий, куяу времени бы сэкономили. Вопрос вообще неправильно поставлен.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что неверно названа причина проблемы. Ошибки в файлах css никакого отношения к jquery не имеют.

Comment: jquery-1-10.1.min.js в этом файле тоже ошибка!!!он тоже не имеет никакого отношения к jquery?а ошибки в файлах CSS касаются цвета в основном, а это НИКАК не влияет на верстку!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56318/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).

Comment: огромное спасибо Вам KAGG Design

Comment: Пожалуйста и удачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KAGG Design  помог мне разобраться в этом вопросе и прийти к выводу, что код указанный мною работает, просто проблема оказалась в другом! Оставляю этот вопрос, т.к. KAGG Design в комментариях приводил много умных аргументов касательно работы библиотеки jquery. Еще огромное спасибо Вам KAGG Design